# Building via TFS 2012 fails to show useful errors

Tags: msbuild

I'm running a CI build via TFS and the build is failing on the build server (not locally).

The error isn't entirely unexpected as it is likely that something needs to be installed on the build server, but there is no error message in the build output.

I have edited the build to set output to "Diagnostic", but still don't get any errors except for the general one below.

I get only this error:

> Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find
>   more specific information about the cause of this error in above
>   messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)
>
> at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>
> at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I can see where the error is caught, farther up the log file, but it is equally information free:

> Handle Exception
>
> Set CompilationStatus to Failed
>
> Initial Property Values
>
> ...
>
> Final Property Values
>
> ...

And there are no indications of an issue before this section.

Is there a way to get better exception messages into the build log?

Comment: I didn't think there were any CodeActivities in the default template, a re you running a custom one?  Can you open in an text editor and look for CodeActivity?

Comment: I can't see any in the built template - but this could also be generated from specific things used in the projects too couldn't it? Like Fakes assemblies?

Comment: Potentially.  Does it succeed if you don't run tests with the build?

Comment: Hi Betty. I know what the issue is in this case now - I had some Visual Studio Fakes in the project and the build server only had Visual Studio premium - but there was no easy way to tell the issue from the build log. I was hoping there was a way of getting better errors. I fudged it by logging on to the build server, opening the solution in the build folder and doing a build and test - not the fastest way of finding out why a build failed :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of decent error messages I just logged in to the build server and ran a build manually in Visual Studio.

My specific issue was that Fakes are only available in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and the build server only has premium.

Comment: Update 2 for Visual Studio 2012 should make this feature available in the Premium edition.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with 2 solutions that were using Microsoft Fakes, but in my case I had VS2012 Ultimate (Update 3) on the build server.

Someone on my team had checked in the FakesAssemblies folders into TFS.  If I renamed the FakesAssemblies folder on the build server to FakesAssemblies2 and set the build to only clean the outputs, the build was able to create the new FakesAssemblies folder and create the files.

If I looked in the FakesAssemblies2 folder (the one that was originally checked into TFS), all of the files are marked as Read-only.  I assume that the build is having an issue with overwriting those files due to the Read-only flag.